# How can I quit my job before the end of my contract after getting a warning letter?

Tags: negotiation, quitting, indonesia

I am currently working as an IT in a Bank. A few days ago, I got a warning letter just because of some mistakes I made. Just after receiving the warning letter, I started to feel stressed with my job. Now I want to quit. However, I still have 1 year contract. I am thinking to talk to my HR about it, and tell her that I feel stressed and not suited with the company, so please fire me instead of sending me a warning letter.

I already got an offer from another Company too.

How can I said it to my Manager and HR?

Edit :

The mistake is because there is someone see I'm sleepy. I already tell to the HR, because I don't get any project and I have nothing to do, but the HR doesn't want to hear it and I don't explain it to them further because I think it will bring a trouble to my Supervisor too.

Until Now I still don't get any job and I feel bored. I am afraid I get used to this situation too relaxed, no project and no improvement to make it difficult for me to work in another company in the future.

I already work 1 year in this Company, still have 1 year left(The contract is 2 year).

The things that make me want to quit too is just because I have a friend in here that in the probation period, she actually already want to Resign but the HR didn't accept it many times and they changes her period from probation become contract without telling her, when she asking a Resign again, the HR just tell her to Pay the Penalty (When you are in the Probation period when you asking a Resign you do not need to pay the Penalty). After I know that things, I just think this place like a Hell that when you get in, it's hard for you to get out.

Thanks for the suggestion for all of you, I will think for a while with my decision.

Comment: What does your 1 year contract obligate you to do? In particular, what does the contract say you have to do if you quit before the 1 year is up?

Comment: Do you have a *written* and *signed* offer from another company?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri I must to pay a Penalty, if I Quit from the Company, but If I get Fired, I do not need to pay. Not Yet, I still have not signed the offer, just some Interview, and they tell me they recruit me.

Comment: @PeteCon Indonesia

Comment: Firing leaves a black mark in your resume and it might prevent work elsewhere. So, please don't think in that way.

Comment: If you are stressed after getting a warning and no longer want to work there I suggest seeking mental guidance. You're likely to get many more warnings in your career and it's most certainly not good to be fired for the sake of it

Answer (score 5):

If you are ready to get fired, then this should be least stressful situation for you.

You do best you can to learn and contribute without worrying about anything else. If your best is not good enough for them, they will fire you which is also an acceptable solution for you.

So just focus on your work and don't try to get fired. Take it easy on yourself and do your best in good faith. Let the situation unfold itself.

Comment: Additionally, start job searching outside of work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make the choice that leaves you with the most options or alternatives. It's important to control your own path as best you can.

You got a warning letter "about some mistakes."  You didn't tell us what sorts of mistakes, so I must guess.  You did some aspect of your work incorrectly, and caused some people some trouble. I guess you didn't steal something or get in a fight, because they would have fired you for that.

So, one choice is to stay with this job and learn from this incident. (Everybody makes mistakes. Some people learn from them.)  Try to put aside the stress and consider: Is this job a waste of my time? Or, can I learn more from working here? Are my colleagues so unpleasant that I don't want to associate with them any more?

Another choice is to take the new job and pay the contract-cancellation penalty. You might consider asking your new employer to help pay the cost of that penalty.

A third choice, inferior in my view, is to accept a firing on your record in place of the penalty. You can replace money. But it's hard to replace a good record.

You did not mention how long you have been in your career. If it is only two or three years, it's possible this is your first job crisis. Everybody who works hard and cares about their work has these crises once in a while. These things are unpleasant but they do pass.

Your career is yours. Think "future perfect." Try to put yourself in your own shoes a decade from now. What was the effect on your career of the choice you made about this crisis? Did you get past the mistake and have a great time with your Bank? Did you stop wasting time at the Bank, pay a penalty, and find a better job?

Decide carefully and dispassionately. And always remember: HR is Not Your Friend.

You'll get through this. Be strong.

Comment: Yeah, it's my first job crisis, I never get it before in my previous company. Thanks for the suggestion